# JSP UTF-8 char encoding error on Glassfish 3.01

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, character-encoding, servlet-filters

I have a rather starange problem. In my web application I use UTF_8 encoding. This works fine until I put a jsp page into my /Protected/ folder. The exact same jsp file works just fine uder my document root. 
To reach the /protected/ folder I use a Filter. 
Like this:

```
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response,
                     FilterChain chain)
throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    HttpServletResponse res = (HttpServletResponse) response;
    HttpSession session = req.getSession();
    PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
    if (session.getAttribute("user") == null){
        // redirect the user to the login page and give error message
             res.sendRedirect("/myApp/login.jsp");
         }
    else {

    chain.doFilter(request, response);

    }
}
```

In my sun-web.xml I have this specified:

```
<locale-charset-info default-locale="">
<parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
</locale-charset-info>
```

And In my jsp files I have this specified:

```
<%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

plus:

Any help is much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the following line in the filter.

```
PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();
```

You only don't need it in a filter at all, but also when the outputstream or writer of the response is been created for the first time, you cannot alter its character encoding afterwards anymore.

Comment: Thanks for your help! It solved my problem. I just used Printwriter out = res.getWriter() for some testing, before the redirection and forgot to remove it. Thanks Again!